# Create a Diagram with script.sql with jdeveloper (reverse-engineering)

Tags: mysql, sql, reverse-engineering, jdeveloper

I've a sql script of my database, but I need to edit my database but I wanna know it's possible make a diagram with sql script in JDeveloper.(Reverse-Engineering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to create a connection to mySQL in JDeveloper and drag the tables into a new Database diagram.